# graphql servlet not started with graphql-java-tools (schema files not found?)

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java-tools

So according to the graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-java-tools a 'graphql' endpoint should become available when the dependency 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter' is added to the project and .graphqls schema files are scanned automatically.

I have the following dependencies:

```
...
        <spring-boot.version>2.3.3.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <graphql.version>7.0.1</graphql.version>
        <graphql-java-tools.version>6.2.0</graphql-java-tools.version>

...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- graphql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${graphql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${graphql.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${graphql-java-tools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

A schema definition:

```
in query.graphqls:
type Query {
    user(username: String!)
    users: [User]
}

in user.graphqls:
type User {
    userId: Number!
    username: String!
}
```

And a GraphQLQueryResolver for that:

```
@Component
public class UserQueryResolver implements GraphQLQueryResolver {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserQueryResolver(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public Iterable<User> users() {
        return this.userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public User user(String username) {
        return this.userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow();
    }
}

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

According to the documentation:

> The servlet becomes accessible at /graphql if graphql-spring-boot-starter added as a dependency to a boot application and a GraphQLSchema bean is present in the application. Check out the simple example for the bare minimum required.

> A GraphQL schema can also be automatically created when a supported graphql-java schema library is found on the classpath.

The graphql-java-tools library should automatically create a schema, under these conditions:

> All GraphQLResolver and GraphQLScalar beans, along with a bean of type SchemaParserDictionary (to provide all other classes), will be used to create a GraphQLSchema. Any files on the classpath named *.graphqls will be used to provide the schema definition. See the Readme for more info.

I think I have everything it needs, but navigating to `localhost:8080/graphql` gives a 404.
N.B.: `localhost:8080/graphiql` works, but it cannot load the schema. It says:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-09-15T12:22:21.748+00:00",
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/graphql"
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: through the browser try /playground

Comment: That also gives a 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the application could not find any JpaRepositories, because the SpringBootApplication starter class was located in *com.package.some.app* while the repositories were in *com.package.some.domain.repositories*. The Component scanner was only scanning components with package *com.package.som.app.**